# Many $.each but seems only 1 $.post get executed

Tags: php, jquery

I'm currently developing a textarea that whatever pasted after the push of button, it will be added to the database. For now, let's leave the database function aside, let's just focus on the data POST event.

Here's I gone so far

jquery

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('#sw').click(function(){
  var fld=$("#txt1").val().split('\n');
  $.each(fld, function(){
    $.post('up.php',
    { 'ldta': this.split('\t') },
    function(data) {
      $('#out').html(data);
      alert(data);
    }
    );
   });
  }
 );
});
</script>
```

html

```
<body>
<form>
 <textarea id="txt1" rows="5" cols="250"></textarea>
 <input type="button" id="sw" value="Add">
</form>
<h2 id="out"></h2>
```

php (up.php)

```
$ldta=$_POST['ldta'];
$out='';
foreach($ldta as $line) {
    if (!$line == "")
    {
        $out.=$line.',';
    }
}
echo $out;
```

Why it seemed only 1 row was posted?
I used

> alert(data);

under the jquery script and I found out that all contents are displayed

I used $out.= to concatenate whatever is being passed
but it seems the php only gets the last row..

Test data to try with (separated with tabs)

```
111 2015-02-11 20:49:00 0.00
222 2015-02-11 20:52:00 0.00
333 2015-02-11 19:25:00 0.00
```

Probably there's something missing on the code? Please let me know

Comment: looks just fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5m1kbuub/1/

Comment: the jquery seems has no problem. what I'm more concerned is the php side..

Comment: are you sure the `this.split('\t')` is sending multiple lines

Comment: I figured out that the php has no problem. I amended the code with `echo 'out='.$out;` and it seems it reads all the rows pasted. I guess the problem is the `<h2 id="out"></h2>` which was solved by the .append(). Thanks for making me know

Answer (score 0):

In you current implementation you send one request per line, so for your test input you will send three independend requests. I suggest you, to build an object that will be parsed by you PHP code before sending it. Try something like that:

```
$(function () {
    $('#sw').click(function () {
        var fld = $("#txt1").val().split('\n')
        ,   data = [];
        $.each(fld, function(index, element){
            data.push({'ldta': element.split(' ')});
        });

        $.post('/echo/html/', {
            html: JSON.stringify(data)
        },
        function (data) {
            $('#out').append(data);
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lwy0wk4c/1/